# Apache Time Differs from Operating System Date and time?

Tags: linux, apache, unix, time

I have apache-tomcat-5.5.17 that I run using the terminal manually the time on the instance is not the same as the operating system , I tried to configure the apache time using php.ini , that is located in /etc/php.ini , I added :
[Date]
date.timezome="MyTimeZone"

it didn't take an effect on the instance even so I restarted the application , and the services , is there something else needs modifying ??

Comment: By `MyTimeZone` you mean literally that string? Or one of the acceptable time-zone strings from http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Comment: it is one of the acceptable timezones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well guys I figured out how to solve this problem , the trick is to modify catalina.sh script and add the time zone to the java options :

-Duser.timezone="one of the Time Zones that are allowed"